# How to use PCLVisualizer realtime dynamic visualized more than 200 cubes

Tags: pcl

It need 2 second to update graph when add 200 cubes.
there is my code.
Is there an efficient drawing method?

```
for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < number; idx++) {
        Eigen::Vector3f center;
        Eigen::Quaternionf rotation(1, 0, 0, 0);

        viewer->addCube(center, rotation, boundingBoxArray[idx].xSize, boundingBoxArray[idx].ySize, boundingBoxArray[idx].zSize,  std::to_string(idx));
        
    }
```